# Excel VB macro copy data

Tags: excel, vba

This macro serves the purpose to copy data from multiple excel sheets from a designated source range and then copies it to a master sheet.

I'm very limited when it comes to VB knowledge. If possible can we augment the macro to skip copying any rows that have blank cells, like a filter? Below the source range is set to B5:N6. Based on our excel sheets column B can be used as a means to apply this filter, i.e. if any cell in column B is empty, then skip that entire row in the copy process. The output would then need to be condensed and not include any spaces between the copied entries as a result of the skipped rows.

```
If VBA7 Then
   Declare PtrSafe Function SetCurrentDirectoryA Lib _
   "kernel32" (ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long
Else
   Declare Function SetCurrentDirectoryA Lib _
   "kernel32" (ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long
End If


Sub ChDirNet(szPath As String)
    SetCurrentDirectoryA szPath
End Sub

Sub Basic_Example_2()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long
    Dim SaveDriveDir As String
    Dim FName As Variant


    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    SaveDriveDir = CurDir
    ChDirNet "C:\Test\"

    FName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", _
                                        MultiSelect:=True)
    If IsArray(FName) Then

        'Add a new workbook with one sheet
        Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
        rnum = 1


        'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
        For Fnum = LBound(FName) To UBound(FName)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(FName(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next
                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("B5:N6")

                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0



                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("A" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
    ChDirNet SaveDriveDir
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `WorksheetFunction.CountA( <row> )` to see which rows are empty

Comment: I am not a coder this is for a work project to simplify my data into a master sheet if you could please provide an example.

Comment: Could you upload a picture of mock data that you're working with and then explain more clearly what it is you're looking to be done to that data?

Comment: Consider using `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlank)` on your range object (`B5:N5`). See [msdn documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells) and also [xlType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcelltype).